# How/when are files in /lib/firmware/amd-ucode/ loaded and applied?

Tags: boot, kernel-modules, firmware

Are the microcodes in `/lib/firmware/amd-ucode/` updated live after each boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How/when

It depends. AMD microcode:

- Can be embedded into the kernel image (vmlinuz)
- Can be loaded via an initrd
- Can be loaded during a normal boot.

This wiki article should answer your question: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/microcode

In all three instances you can reload it manually once you have updated it.

Comment: this wiki page is helpful too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Microcode